# Android 2.3 command line - accessing GPS native way

Tags: android, gps, command-line-interface

Is it possible to obtain NMEA or even just lat/lon from android root command line? I've looked in /sys - there are some folders like nmea but there is no control interface. I've also digged into /dev - "nmea" device is present but reading is impossible.

I know that Android 4+ use gpsd but my platform have only 256MB of RAM, so installing it will be a horrible mistake.

I also wanna make calls and read sms's but that can be easily done using AT commands.

p.s. I'm not using NDK because I use scripting language.

Answer (score -1):

if the android device is rooted you can look in the /cache folder. Some of the services that generate locations will store them there, particularly cell and wifi.

Comment: It's not an solution - it's a hack. I wanna get real location realtime.

Comment: As this is not a standard feature that anything that works will be a hack of some sort. Could you get users to install an app? that would make the problem much simpler to solve